# how to insert char at multiple position from end of the string

Tags: ruby, string, algorithm

input like this:

```
100000000
1000
100
100000
10000
```

i need to start inserting char (,) from end of the string.first time after three char from end and then repeat the insert (,) after every 2 char

output

```
10,00,00,000
1,000
100
1,00,000
10,000
```

any hint guys how can i do this, i need to start inserting char(',')  from end of the string.

thanks!

Comment: What is "inert"? How are "tag(,)" and "char(',')" different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two ways, the first using a regular expression, the last just inserting commas in a loop.

```
a = %w| 100000000 1000 100 100000 10000 |
  #=> ["100000000", "1000", "100", "100000", "10000"]
```

**#1 Use a regex**

```
r = /
    (?<=\d)    # match digit in positive lookbehind
    \d{2}      # match two digits
    (?=        # begin positive lookahead
    (?:\d{2})* # match two digits, repeated zero or more times
    \d         # match last digit
    \z         # match end of string
    )          # end positive lookahead
    /x         # extended mode

a.each { |s| puts "#{s} -> #{ s.gsub(r) { |ss| ',' + ss } }" }
100000000 -> 10,00,00,000
1000 -> 1,000
100 -> 100
100000 -> 1,00,000
10000 -> 10,000
```

This regex is similar to the one given earlier by @Avinish, but I chose to use a positive lookbehind and no capture group, and presented it in extended mode to help readers understand how it worked. I would use a regular expression here.

**#2 Insert commas**

If you do not wish to use a regular expression, you could determine the position of the last comma to insert (`p` below), the number of commas to insert (`n` below) and then insert them, back to front:

```
def insert_commas(string)
  sz = string.size
  str = string.dup
  p = sz - 3
  n = (sz - 2)/2
  n.times { str.insert(p, ','); p -= 2 }
  str
end

a.each { |s| puts "#{s} -> #{insert_commas(s)}" }
100000000 -> 10,00,00,000
1000 -> 1,000
100 -> 100
100000 -> 1,00,000
10000 -> 10,000
```

I `dup`ed `string` on the assumption you did not want to mutate `string`.

Alternatively,

```
def insert_commas(string)
  sz = string.size
  return string if sz < 4
  p = sz.even? ? 1 : 2
  string[0,p] + string[p..-2].gsub(/\d{2}/) { |s| ",#{s}" } + string[-1]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below positive lookahead based regex.

```
gsub(/(\d)(?=(?:\d{2})*\d{3}$)/, "$1,")
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iM2pO9/1)

Comment: You can use lookbehind to get rid of `$1`.

Comment: How is a newline character relevant?

Comment: or `(?<=\d)(?=(?:\d{2})*\d{3}$)` replace with `,`

Comment: Avainash, yes, but please disregard my comment. I misunderstood your regex.

Comment: I believe you want `r = /(\d{1,2})(?=(?:\d{2})*\d{3}$)/; s.gsub(r, "#{'\1'},")`.